# How to fix stuttering audio playback with Soundcloud?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, audio

On my HTC desire 510, Android ver. 4.4.3 audio playback is unreliable. I encounter stuttering playback when using Soundcloud. As Soundcloud buffers everything locally and the problem is reoccurring when playing offline this can't be a streaming (network) issue.

Are there any knobs and wheels I can fiddle with?